# ASP: call objects stored in new class

Tags: class, dictionary, asp-classic

Here is a simplified example of my code to show how my classes look like...
Both classes are in seperate asp files (newsitem.asp and messageboard.asp)

```
Class NewsItem
    private c_title
    private c_content

    public property get title
        title = c_title
    end property 

    public property get content
        content = c_content
    end property

    public function loadById (id)
        'Fill all the variables with database records'
        c_title = rs(...)
        c_content = rs(...)
    end function
End Class

Class MessageBoard
    Dim dict

    private sub Class_Initialize
         set dict = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")     
    end sub

    public property get messages ()
        messages = dict
    end property

    public function fillBoard ()
        Dim oNews : set oNews = new NewsItem

        For all the newsitems in the database
            oNews.loadByID(newsitemID)
            dict.add newsitemsID, oNews
        Next
    end function
End Class
```

In a third file (showMessageboard.asp) I include the above 2 files and try to do the following:

```
Dim oMB : set oMB = new MessageBoard
oMB.fillBoard() 'Dictionary of MessageBoard class is filled with NewsItem-objects'
response.write oMB.messages.item(1).content 'show the content of the first NewsItem-object'
```

I always receive an error on this last line saying something about the object properties that don't support the method (I don't know the exact error message at the moment, because I'm not at home :) Will add it later on).

Can anybody have a look at this code and tell me what could be wrong? I tested my code by adding *response.write dict.item(1).content* to the *public property get messages* and it worked fine. So something goes wrong when using the dictionary outside the class???

I also tried using a *function* instead of *public property*, but it had the same result...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in your property get Messages() you have to SET the return value like so:

```
public property get messages ()
    set messages = dict
end property
```

Comment: Ok, this was a stupid mistake :) Thanks for pointing this out!